# Iterating backwards with for-loop doesn't work

Tags: swift, loops

I'm a newbie on Swift and I'm really confused about how to iterate backward with for-loop.

my array:

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Trying for-loop that i googled:

```
for i in stride(from: arr.count, through: 0, by: -1) {
print(arr[i]) }
```

Output: Terminated by signal 4

Another attempt that doesn't work:

```
for i in arr.count...0 {
    print(arr[i])
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: First Google result for `Swift iterate array backwards` is [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-loop-through-an-array-in-reverse). Wondering how did you come up with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them doesn't work because you start at `arr.count`, which is always an invalid index for an array. The last valid index is `arr.count - 1`, so changing the start of the stride/range to that will fix the problem.

If you want to iterate through the indices in reverse, you can just get the `indices` and `reverse` it:

```
for i in arr.indices.reversed() {
    let element = arr[i]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `enumerated().reversed()`, but note that `reversed()` here will first create an extra array to hold the reversed indices and elements, which means that you will be looping through `arr` an extra time.

```
for (i, element) in arr.enumerated().reversed() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the point that array indices – in almost all programming languages – are zero based, so the last index is `count - 1`

```
for i in stride(from: arr.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    print(arr[i])
}
```